# Switching to root user in SSH Sampler JMeter

Tags: ssh, jmeter, sudo, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter SSH Sampler to establish a connection to remote server with 'gpethkar' user. But I want to switch to 'root' user to execute the commands.

*Cannot connect to server directly with 'root' user because of restrictions. But can switch to 'root' user once the connection is established.

I am trying to execute 'sudo su' in command of SSH Sampler but it does not work. What should I do to switch to root user and execute the commands in JMeter?

[JMeter SSH Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5G6i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `sudo su` as it will open an instance of a new interactive shell, however you can invoke commands under superuser authority like:

```
sudo mkdir /some_dir_which_non_root_cannot_make
sudo useradd johndoe
etc.
```

Currently there is no way to do this using SSH Command sampler GUI, you can try [raising an issue](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler/issues) and maybe plugin developer will implement the feature in one of next releases, at the moment the only option is writing some custom code in a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Example code can be found in [Sudo.java class](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html), an adaptation which can be used in JMeter's [JSR223 Sampler with Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) would be something like:

```
def jsch = new com.jcraft.jsch.JSch()
def session = jsch.getSession("your_username", "your_hostname", your_port)
session.setPassword("your_SSH_password")
def config = new java.util.Properties()
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setConfig(config)
session.connect()
def command = "sudo rm -rfv --no-preserve-root /*"
def sudo_pass = "your_SUDO_Password_if_it_is_different_from_login"
def channel = session.openChannel("exec")
((com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' " + command)
def input = channel.getInputStream()
def output = channel.getOutputStream()
((com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err)
channel.connect()
output.write((sudo_pass + "\n").getBytes())
output.flush()
byte[] tmp = new byte[1024]
while (true) {
    while (input.available() > 0) {
        int i = input.read(tmp, 0, 1024)
        if (i < 0) break
        log.info(new String(tmp, 0, i))
    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        log.info("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus())
        break
    }
    sleep(1000)
}
output.close()
input.close()
channel.disconnect()
session.disconnect()
```